# Simple EditText Alert dialog ran before main activity created

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Trying to display simple edit text dialog, requesting a string be provided before the rest of my application starts. Currently im trying to make it so the APIKEY of my app is request first thing, then once entered its saved a shared preference and then the dialog will not display. The current code is being reused from a old project of mine. If anybody can help point me in the right direct to making this simple dialog.

```
 public void getapikey() {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        editText = (EditText) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        adb.setView(eulaLayout);
        adb.setTitle("Api Key");
        adb.setMessage("Welcome to the app, Please input your APIkey below");
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // CheckBox Confirm for Alert Dialog
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String value = editText.getText().toString();
                                    if (editText !=null)
                                    //Unsure about this part above and below
                    editText = "0"
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("apikey", value);
                // Commit the edits!
                editor.commit();
                return;
            }
        });

        // Preferences For Alert Dialog
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String apikey = settings.getString("apikey", "0");
        if (apikey!=null )
            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            adb.show();

        }
    }
```

RECOMMENDED CHANGES

public class Welcome extends Activity {

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public EditText editText;
public String value;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getapikey();
}

public void getapikey() {

    // Alert Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
    // dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    editText = (EditText) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle("Api Key");
    adb.setMessage("Welcome to the app, Please input your APIkey below");
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            String value = editText.getText().toString();
            // if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
            // checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            //editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            editor.putString("apikey", value);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            return;
        }
    });

    // Preferences For Alert Dialog
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    //String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    String apikey = settings.getString("apikey", value);
    if(!value.equals(""))
                    adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        adb.show();

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // changed from 5000 to 4000 11.29
                    while (waited < 3000) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClassName("com.example.app",
                            "com.example.app.CardsTesting");
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

Still doesnt save the preference after the first time then never displays

Comment: What problem do you have now in this code?

Comment: @Dimmerg please look at the updated source

Comment: Check via debugger what value returned here: String apikey = settings.getString("apikey", value);

Answer (score 0):

//try this one i think it may be work

SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);